# Reference current user when creating a content type

Tags: users

I am creating a new content type and one of the fields I d like to add owner.

I ve chosen reference - user as the field type 
Type of item to reference = user

How do I make the default value the name of the current user?

Many Thanks

Comment: Content types already has an author field that will automatically populate with the user creating the node. Can't you use that and save creating another field?

Comment: unfortunately not as I want to keep the created on and have a second one that may be the same or different, would the repopulate module help with this maybe?

Answer (score 0):

You can set default values in a [hook_ENTITY_TYPE_create](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_ENTITY_TYPE_create/8.7.x):

```
/**
 * Implements hook_ENTITY_TYPE_create() for 'node'.
 */
function mymodule_node_create(\Drupal\node\NodeInterface $node) {
  if ($node->getType() == 'my_content_type') {
    $node->field_user->target_id = \Drupal::currentUser()->id();
  }
}
```